# Visual Studio 2012 C++ Windows 32

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I had to switch to a new computer (64-bit, of course). I installed Visual Studio 2012 as before and opened my projects. I have code which is compiled for 64-bit and for 32-bit windows in two different projects, setting some constants and #ifdef statements. The first is x64 and the second ARM. However, Windows 7 32-bit claims that the second one is not a proper Win32 application and refused to start the EXE (users told me that and I confirmed in an XP installation in a virtual box). However, everything workd fine on my previous computer (a 64-bit computer too) and I did not change a word in the settings or the code.

Now I know that this is difficult to answer without details. But maybe someone has an idea what could go wrong.

I try to provide some details below:

```
Compiler Switches: /GS /analyze- /W4 /wd"4100" /wd"4127" /wd"4701" /wd"4703" /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"Release\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "FLOAT_TEST" /D "DLL" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "YACAS" /D "CATCH" /D "PYTHON" /fp:except /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MT /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\euler.pch"



Linker Switches: /OUT:"\euler\euler.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"\euler\euler.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "Shlwapi.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comctl32.lib" "winmm.lib" "gdiplus.lib" "wininet.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /STACK:"32000000" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"\euler\euler.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\euler.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

The project type is set to "Release" and "Win32". It says "ARM" in the box below the menu bar.

Thanks for any help.

R.G.

Comment: XP doesn't run on an ARM target - you want an x86 target for 32-bit Windows. However, your linker command line shows that it's targeting x86. I suspect that you need to have the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed on the target machine.

Comment: The /SUBSYSTEM linker option is wrong.  VS2012 by default will generate executables that only run on Vista or higher.  Yet another unsubtle reminder that XP is truly over and done with.  Project > Properties > General > Platform Toolset = v120_xp.  Be sure to have the updates installed as well, this option wasn't available until Update 1.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that Windows XP is no longer supported by default, as Hans Passant pointed out. I gave up supporting this version. The program runs on Windows 7 32-bit just fine.

Comment: True, you can still install the old VS2010 build tools if XP support is desirable, though.